# Unsigned Jar Error when the Jar is signed

Tags: java, java-web-start, sign

Please do not say this is a Duplicate of another question because I have taken some time to go through other similar questions but My Problem is Unique. I am trying to run a jar using JNLP webstart and the error is:

```
 com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://Stanley/A-Skul.jar
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Problem is My Jar is signed and After googling around I found that I need to tick enable temporary File in My local computer whcih is already done. The problem still persists. I am running Java 1.7. Here is My JNLP file:

```
<jnlp codebase="http://Stanley" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
  <information>
    <title>A-Skul</title>
    <vendor>pc</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>A-Skul</description>
    <description kind="short">A-Skul</description>
    <icon href="Free bsd.png" kind="default"/>
  </information>
  <update check="always"/>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="A-Skul.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/derby.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/mail.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/ojdbc14.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/itext-2.0.1.jar'.jar'.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-lang-2.0.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="a.skul.ASkul"/>
</jnlp>
```

And My Console:

```
Java Web Start 10.10.2.18
Using JRE version 1.7.0_10-b18 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\pc
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
    Match: beginTraversal
Match: digest selected JREDesc: JREDesc[version 1.7+, heap=-1--1, args=null, href=null, sel=false, null, null], JREInfo: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_10
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: null
    native platform is: Windows, x86 [ x86, 32bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.4 found at C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: true

    Match: ignoring maxHeap: -1
    Match: ignoring InitHeap: -1
    Match: digesting vmargs: null
    Match: digested vmargs: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: JVM args after accumulation: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: digest LaunchDesc: http://Stanley/launch.jnlp
    Match: digest properties: []
    Match: JVM args: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: endTraversal ..
    Match: JVM args final: 
    Match: Running JREInfo Version    match: 1.7.0.10 == 1.7.0.10
     Match: Running JVM args match: have:<>  satisfy want:<>
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### Found unsigned entry in resource: http://Stanley/A-Skul.jar
```

This Jar is signed and I have Compiled it using Netbeans. Anyone who has come accross this error Please help.

Comment: have you signed all libs as well??

Comment: Nikolay, I thought the libraries are signed automatically by the signer when you sign through netbeans self generated Key? But the Error says the A-Skul Jat is the one that is unsigned and this is the Application jar.

Comment: Sign all libraries as well before deployment